# Selenium - capture FORM submit

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html page that does a form submit when the page loads. The page has hidden fields. From fiddler, I can see that the form is submitted but I don't see anything on web page. The page still points to previous page. 
I need to capture output of the page after form submission. I don't see 
the php page

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <noscript>
JavaScript is required 
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://different.page.com/jsdisabled.html"/>
</noscript>
        <title>Continue</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">function DoSubmit(){document.frm.submit();}}</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:DoSubmit();">
        <form name="frm" id="frm" action="https://different.page.com/login.php" method="post" target="_top">
            <input type="hidden" name="wa1" id="wa1" value="w10">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update:
I believe the behavior is because of `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://different.page.com/jsdisabled.html"/>`. In IE the page redirects but not in chrome.

Comment: Does that page is created? which display submitted data?

Comment: What is the question? Why are the selenium related tags on this?